# Carrierwave/Paperclip and Resque - Sharing across several computers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave, distributed-computing, resque

I am working on a rails application that requires files to be uploaded to my server and then have resque workers (running on several other computers) use those files to do some tasks. I have my workers all set to do the task but I can't seem to find a nice way to get the files from my host computer to my worker computers. I've tried Carrierwave (and looked the documentation for Paperclip), but all I see is using S3 which I cannot use. My only idea is to store a string which contains the URI where the file may be found so that the workers can download them and start working. I'm not particularly fond this idea. Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be best way to do this? Thank you!

---

Update

I should also note the files that need to be shared are roughly 200MB each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered something like a [Network File System](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) instead of doing this inside your application?

Depending on what platform your workers and server are you should have numerous options to share a filesystem (I assume you have a LAN running between them).

And even if no real LAN, [sshfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) could work too..

The upsides are obvious: Your Ruby application only has to deal with a regular filesystem using FileUtils and the heavy lifting of pushing stuff around is handled by a much more reliable infrastructure